# Powermock of static class gives error: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class XXX

Tags: static, junit4, powermock, powermockito

### Problem

Could not initialize class ...

- ...`javax.xml.transform.FactoryFinder` (in our case).
- In the article, where we found the solution, it was the class `SessionFactory`.

#### Class Under Test

We wanted to write a test for a utils class with static members.
We got the error when trying to create a Mock of a class, which contained a `new` statement as an initialization of a static field.

```java
public class ClassUnderTest{
    private static JavaType javaType =  new JavaType();
    // ...
}
```

#### Test Class

```java
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest(ClassUnderTest.class)
public class TestForClassUnderTest {

    @Test
    public void testCase() {

        PowerMockito.mockStatic(ClassUnderTest.class);
```

Answer (score 3):

### Solution

The solution was adding another class level annotation to the test class:

```java
@SuppressStaticInitializationFor("com.example.package.util.ClassUnderTest")
```

Note, that you have to give the package path and no `.class` at the end. Unlike `@PrepareFor`.

Thanks to this article: http://www.gitshah.com/2010/06/how-to-suppress-static-initializers.html

#### Test Class with Solution

```java
//...
import org.powermock.core.classloader.annotations.PrepareForTest;
import org.powermock.core.classloader.annotations.SuppressStaticInitializationFor;

@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest(ClassUnderTest.class)
@SuppressStaticInitializationFor("com.example.package.util.ClassUnderTest") // <-- this is it :)
public class TestForClassUnderTest {

  @Test
  public void testCase() {
    PowerMockito.mockStatic(ClassUnderTest.class);
    //...
  }
}
```